# Rigorous theory behind overfitting

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting, methodology, mathematical-statistics

I am taking an intro to ML class, and in my limited experience, training ML algorithms (validation, overfitting etc.) feels a bit like black magic. For instance, you aren't supposed to touch the test set for the fear of 'tainting' it.

Of course there is a good intuitive explanation for every step of the process, but most of these explanations feel a little handwavy.

Is there a general, rigorous mathematical theory of validation/training methods? If so, where can I learn more about it?

Comment: Have a look at https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf, maybe section 7.10 Cross-Validation